# Why token is not being updated on silent_renew.html (oidc-client)

Tags: reactjs, openid-connect

I have the following AuthProvider in my app:

```js
import { AuthProvider, AuthProviderProps } from 'oidc-react';

const AuthWrapper = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const userManagerConfig: AuthProviderProps = {
    clientId: 'my_client_id',
    responseType: 'code',
    redirectUri: `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}${
      window.location.port ? `:${window.location.port}` : ''
    }/callback`,
    scope: 'openid profile',
    authority: 'my_sso_authority',
    silentRedirectUri: `${window.location.protocol}//${
      window.location.hostname
    }${
      window.location.port ? `:${window.location.port}` : ''
    }/silent_renew.html`,
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    loadUserInfo: true,
    autoSignIn: true,
    onSignIn: (user: any) => {
      console.log('onSignIn', user);
      sessionStorage.setItem('token', user.id_token);
      dispatch(loadtToken(user.id_token));
    }
  };
  return <AuthProvider {...userManagerConfig}>{children}</AuthProvider>;
};
```

And the following script in `silent_renew.html`:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/oidc-client/1.10.0/oidc-client.js></script>
<script>
  new Oidc.UserManager()
    .signinSilentCallback()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('refreshed');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
</script>
```

When signing in I see that my `onSignIn` callback is working correctly.
But when it's time to visit `silent_renew.html`, I can see that eventually `console.log('refreshed')` statement is reached (with no arguments in the callback BTW) but the token in sessionStorage remains the same.

I tried to changed it to `new Oidc.UserManager().signinSilent()...` while passing config to the constructor but it resulted to some errors.

I doubt that my `silent_renew.html` is actually correct. Does anyone know whether it should work this way?

Answer (score 1):

The code looks right. The oidc-client library runs a timer due to the `automaticSilentRenew` setting, which manages token refresh using the SSO session cookie.

The library looks at the `expires_in` field of token responses. Before the access token expires, `signInSilent` is called. This spins up a hidden iframe that runs a code flow using the OpenID Connect `prompt=none` parameter.

**AUTHORIZATION RESPONSE**

So far we have established that the code flow succeeds. By adding this line:

```js
console.log(location.href);
```

You see that the authorization code is received correctly with a response of this form:

```
https://www example.com?code=xxx&state=yyy
```

The iframe posts this URL to the main window, which [swaps the code for tokens](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/blob/dev/src/TokenClient.js#L20).

**TROUBLESHOOTING**

It looks like this step is failing so you need to debug. This can be done by subscribing to the [silentRenewError event](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/blob/dev/src/UserManagerEvents.js#L47).

Alternatively you can do this, then ensure that verbose logging is configured in browser tools:

```js
import {Log} from 'oidc-client';

Log.level = Log.DEBUG;
```

**FURTHER INFO**

My [blog posts](https://authguidance.com/home/mainindex/) cover the SPA journey, which is trickier than you may think. The one on `Silent Token Renewal` has further info on its problem areas.

Comment: Nope, the link looks like this: `https://my-app-domain/silent_renew.html?code=xxx&locale=en_US&state=some_code&userState=Authenticated`. I tried to enable third-party cookies in my Incognito and also to try in a normal session but it still doesn't work. Let me try to follow your links.

Comment: Well that's the hard part done and you are receiving the authorization code. Next the iframe posts the response URL to the main window, which sends an [authorization code grant](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/blob/dev/src/TokenClient.js#L20) to get tokens. You may need to get the library logging working. My resources have some info on that.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I realized that actually this script/page has nothing to do with sessionStorage. I would say the problem is that `onSignIn()` in my provider is called only once – when actually signing in. But do you know, can I somehow make it executing after silent_renew.html redirect happens?

Comment: The `automaticSilentRenew` setting means the library takes care of calling `signinSilent` for you, so I think your code is right. Meanwhile I updated my answer with some info on troubleshooting.

Comment: Many thanks for improving your answer. I mean should it call some callback in my `AuthWrapper` because of `automaticSilentRenew` is set to true (which is a default value BTW as far as I understand)? Or to be more specific: should `onSignIn` be called as a result of silent_renew.html redirect (in principle, considering everything is working correctly)?

Comment: automaticSilentRenew causes an iframe to be created at an authorization request URL. This triggers an invisible login and the silent_renew.html is executed when the authorization response is received, and your signInSilentCallback call should get tokens and save them to storage. Your main app just picks up the new tokens when it calls APIs.

Comment: Just a quick question if you can help – in `then` followed after `signinSilentCallback` I don't have any arguments. Is that expected behavior? How I can get the new token in silent_renew.html page script?

Comment: Yes it is - that page runs in an iframe and only receives the authorization response URL. It posts that URL to the main window, which gets the authorization code from the authorization response URL and swaps it for tokens.

Comment: So it's expected that `onSignIn` is called in `AuthWrapper` after visiting `silent_renew.html`?

Comment: I would say the problem is also that the my-sso-app.com/token request is also never happening.